# Typescript typeguard unexpected behavior

Tags: typescript

I have the following code written for TypeScript 4:

```
type CacheType = Record<string, string>;

function get(key: string, caches: CacheType[]) {
    const myCaches = Array.from(caches);
    const cachesWithoutValue: CacheType[] = [];
    let myValue: string | undefined;
    while (!myValue && myCaches.length) {
        const currentCache = myCaches.pop()!;
        myValue = currentCache[key];
        if (myValue) {
            cachesWithoutValue.forEach(cache => { cache[key] = myValue });
        } else {
            cachesWithoutValue.push(currentCache);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgYwBYQCrmgXigJQggewCcATAHgGdgiBLAOwHMAaKK2xgPgG4AoHgMwCudBMBoE6UBhGAAKANYQQALlbV6zKAkQoKq%20MjQYA2gF0AlFADePKHa0SqUALYgDuqNgCCRInBAAdPxEBM6y2oYU5rz2DnROEboA6jTASASCwABqcAA2ghD6OkaQZp5QZjH2uTIuIDn5hWrsDFAAPlDCJBD89BAkVXYA7kg0NVCyAISuDQVQAGTzde4QFAE1jGmWNrGxhPHAWoK%20EHTAK%20WuK2tgBGCy5pODuzN5c9gIx0Sn58XGiiBTM9YjR%20BNXo1trZdjDEqsUmkMtk3hAgsQAKI6cLFTwcaxaP4A0yXeooqAAX2i0Jh5KgEFyFGgOxhuzhFAR6Uys1RYEEFCQ4S%20PxWVJZFOp4vJQA)

I expect this to be compile-able. However, I got this compilation error on the `cache[key] = myValue` assignment:

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

Which is weird as I have the `if` check so the type of `myValue` should be narrowed to `string`.

If I change the code a bit into this:

```
type CacheType = Record<string, string>;

function get(key: string, caches: CacheType[]) {
    const myCaches = Array.from(caches);
    const cachesWithoutValue: CacheType[] = [];
    let myValue: string | undefined;
    while (!myValue && myCaches.length) {
        const currentCache = myCaches.pop()!;
        const myCurrValue = currentCache[key];
        if (myCurrValue) {
            cachesWithoutValue.forEach(cache => { cache[key] = myCurrValue });
        } else {
            cachesWithoutValue.push(currentCache);
        }
        myValue = myCurrValue;
    }
}
```

Then I don't have any compilation error anymore. What is the explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you are in the callback function for `.forEach`, typescript can't be sure that this code is running synchronously. You and I know that `forEach` is synchronous, but typescript doesn't. There isn't any type information that can show that `forEach` callbacks are synchronous while, for example, `setTimeout` callbacks are not, so typescript plays it safe and assumes that things might change. So even though you checked for undefined with `if (myValue) {`, typescript isn't sure that by the time the callback runs it will still be defined.

There's a few ways you could address this. One is to rearrange your variables and make it a `const`, like you did in your second piece of code. By doing this, typescript now knows that it's impossible for the value to change, and so checking for undefined once is valid forever. In most cases, this is how i'd recommend fixing the issue.

Another option is to use a different loop which is guaranteed to be synchronous. For example:

```
if (myValue) {
  for (const cache of cachesWithoutValue) {
    cache[key] = myValue;
  }
}
```

And another option is to assert to typescript that you know what you're doing and that it will definitely be defined. I'd recommend avoiding this, since it reduces type safety.

```
if (myValue) {
  cachesWithoutValue.forEach(cache => { cache[key] = myValue! });
}
```